# Uploading HTML into database - PERL

Tags: mysql, html, perl

im trying to upload HTML into a database which does work for some files but not all.

```
my $fileContents;
if( $md5Con =~ m/\.php$/g ) {
    my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($DB_ftpserver, Debug => 0) or die "Cannot connect to some.host.name: $@";
    $ftp->login($DB_ftpuser, $DB_ftppass) or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;
    ftp->get("/" . $root . $webpage, "c:/perlscripts/" . md5_hex($md5Con) . "-code.php") or die $ftp->message;
    my $file = "c:/perlscripts/" . md5_hex($md5Con) . "-code.php";
    {
       local( $/ ); # undefine the record seperator
       open FILE, "<", $file or die "Cannot open:$!\n";
       my $fileContents = <FILE>;
       #print $fileContents;
       my $bodyContents;
       my $headContents;

       my @contentsArray = split( /<\/head>/is, $fileContents, 2);

       if( scalar @contentsArray == 2 ){
           $bodyContents = $dbh->quote(trim($contentsArray[1]));
           $headContents = $dbh->quote(trim($contentsArray[0]) . "</head>");

           $dbh->do($createBodyTable) or die " error: Couldn't create body table: " . DBI->errstr;
           $dbh->do($createHeadTable) or die " error: Couldn't create header table: " . DBI->errstr;
           $dbh->do("INSERT INTO $headerTable ( headData, headDataOutput ) VALUES ( $headContents, $headContents )") or die " error: Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;
           $dbh->do("INSERT INTO $bodyTable ( bodyData, bodyDataOutput ) VALUES ( $bodyContents, $bodyContents )") or die " error: Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;
           $dbh->do("INSERT INTO page_names (linkFromRoot, linkTrue, page_name, table_name, navigation, location) VALUES ( $linkFromRoot, $linkTrue, $page_name, $table_name, $navigation, $location )") or die " error: Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;

           unlink("c:/perlscripts/" . md5_hex($md5Con) . "-code.php");
       }else{
           print "<span class=\"red\">" . $md5Con . " cannot be used by our CMS, invalid data.</span><br />\n";
       }
   }
   $ftp->quit;
}
```

can anyone see why this maybe happening?

**EDIT**

To see at a different angle, this is the output of the data going into the database... The first 3 blocks of code go in fine then errors on the fourth.

```
<span class="green">http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/index.php</span><br />

'<?php session_start(); ?>\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"h
ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n<meta name=\"description\" content=\"The Mo
bile Makeover offers a wide range of services and treatments all from the luxuary of your own home!\" />\n<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"Mobile Makeover, B
eauty Therapist, Beautician, Therapist, Mobile Therapist, Mansfield, Nottinghamshire\" />\n<meta name=\"language\" content=\"en\" />\n<meta name=\"author\" co
ntent=\"ACT Web Designs\" />\n<meta name=\"copyright\" content=\"The Mobile Makeover\" />\n<meta name=\"publisher\" content=\"ACT Web Designs\" />\n<meta name
=\"country\" content=\"United Kingdom\" />\n<meta name=\"city\" content=\"Mansfield, Nottinghamshire\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=8
\" /> \n<meta name=\"verify-v1\" content=\"4lZIaMmjLMq+UA8nkPYB9RjF5RreNwF3Mzurm9JYvQM=\" />\n<title>The Mobile Makeover - Mobile Beautician</title>\n<link hr
ef=\"stylesheets/main.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n<link href=\"stylesheets/cssReset.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n<script
type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery-1.3.1.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.bgpos.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/java
script\" src=\"js/jquery.timers.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/makeover.scroll.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nv
ar gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"https://ssl.\" : \"http://www.\");\ndocument.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src=\'\" + gaJsHost + \"
google-analytics.com/ga.js\' type=\'text/javascript\'%3E%3C/script%3E\"));\n</script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\ntry {\nvar pageTracker = _gat._getTr
acker(\"UA-8193659-6\");\npageTracker._trackPageview();\n} catch(err) {}</script></head>'

<span class="green">http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/about-us-the-mobile-makeover.php</span><br />

'<?php session_start(); ?>\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"h
ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n<meta name=\"description\" content=\">My na
me is Kelly Knight, I am a highly Qualifed Mobile Beauty Therapist. I have trained in NVQ Level 2 and NVQ level 3 in Beauty Therapy with many additional cours
es and training...\" />\n<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"Mobile Makeover, About Us, Beauty Therapist, Mobile Therapist, Mansfield, Nottinghamshire\" />\n<me
ta name=\"language\" content=\"en\" />\n<meta name=\"author\" content=\"ACT Web Designs\" />\n<meta name=\"copyright\" content=\"The Mobile Makeover\" />\n<me
ta name=\"publisher\" content=\"ACT Web Designs\" />\n<meta name=\"country\" content=\"United Kingdom\" />\n<meta name=\"city\" content=\"Mansfield, Nottingha
mshire\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=8\" /> \n<title>The Mobile Makeover - About Us</title>\n<link href=\"stylesheets/main.css\" rel
=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n<link href=\"stylesheets/cssReset.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"
js/jquery-1.3.1.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.bgpos.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.timers
.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/makeover.scroll.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == d
ocument.location.protocol) ? \"https://ssl.\" : \"http://www.\");\ndocument.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src=\'\" + gaJsHost + \"google-analytics.com/ga.js\' ty
pe=\'text/javascript\'%3E%3C/script%3E\"));\n</script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\ntry {\nvar pageTracker = _gat._getTracker(\"UA-8193659-6\");\npageT
racker._trackPageview();\n} catch(err) {}</script></head>'

<span class="green">http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/beauty-products-used.php</span><br />

'<?php session_start(); ?>\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"h
ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n<meta name=\"description\" content=\"We use
 a wide range of the finest products on the market today. Below is a short brief of just a few of the names which we believe give you the best results - we do
 not compromise when it comes to quality.\" />\n<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"Mobile Makeover, Beauty Therapist, Beauty Products, Jessica, Calgel, Eve Tay
lor, Tantrick, Therapist, Mansfield, Nottinghamshire\" />\n<meta name=\"language\" content=\"en\" />\n<meta name=\"author\" content=\"ACT Web Designs\" />\n<m
eta name=\"copyright\" content=\"The Mobile Makeover\" />\n<meta name=\"publisher\" content=\"ACT Web Designs\" />\n<meta name=\"country\" content=\"United Ki
ngdom\" />\n<meta name=\"city\" content=\"Mansfield, Nottinghamshire\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=8\" /> \n<title>The Mobile Makeov
er - Beauty Products Used</title>\n<link href=\"stylesheets/main.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n<link href=\"stylesheets/cssReset.css\" rel=\"
stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n<!--[if lte IE 6]><link href=\"stylesheets/mainie6.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /><![endif]-->\n<script type=
\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery-1.3.1.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.bgpos.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascrip
t\" src=\"js/jquery.timers.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/makeover.scroll.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar ga
JsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"https://ssl.\" : \"http://www.\");\ndocument.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src=\'\" + gaJsHost + \"googl
e-analytics.com/ga.js\' type=\'text/javascript\'%3E%3C/script%3E\"));\n</script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\ntry {\nvar pageTracker = _gat._getTracker
(\"UA-8193659-6\");\npageTracker._trackPageview();\n} catch(err) {}</script></head>'

<span class="green">http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/beauty-treatments.php</span><br />

'<?php session_start(); ?>\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"h
ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n<meta name=\"description\" content=\"The Mo
bile Makeover offers a wide range of treatments all from the luxuary of your own home!\" />\n<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"Mobile Makeover, Beauty Treatme
nts, Beautician, Facials, Pedicures, Hopi Ear Candles, Eye Treatments, Mansfield, Nottinghamshire\" />\n<meta name=\"language\" content=\"en\" />\n<meta name=
\"author\" content=\"ACT Web Designs\" />\n<meta name=\"copyright\" content=\"The Mobile Makeover\" />\n<meta name=\"publisher\" content=\"ACT Web Designs\" /
>\n<meta name=\"country\" content=\"United Kingdom\" />\n<meta name=\"city\" content=\"Mansfield, Nottinghamshire\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" c
ontent=\"IE=8\" /> \n<title>The Mobile Makeover - Beauty Treatments</title>\n<link href=\"stylesheets/main.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n<lin
k href=\"stylesheets/cssReset.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery-1.3.1.js\"></script>\n<script ty
pe=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.bgpos.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.timers.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javas
cript\" src=\"js/makeover.scroll.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"https://ssl
.\" : \"http://www.\");\ndocument.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src=\'\" + gaJsHost + \"google-analytics.com/ga.js\' type=\'text/javascript\'%3E%3C/script%3E\"))
;\n</script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\ntry {\nvar pageTracker = _gat._getTracker(\"UA-8193659-6\");\npageTracker._trackPageview();\n} catch(err) {}<
/script></head>'


DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use nea
r '22e64cef7d70fa952ce7444f158e2c4e_header ( headData, headDataOutput ) VALUES ( '<' at line 1 at C:\perlscripts\cgitest.pl line 360, <FILE> chunk 4.

 error: Couldn't connect to database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right synta
x to use near '22e64cef7d70fa952ce7444f158e2c4e_header ( headData, headDataOutput ) VALUES ( '<' at line 1 at C:\perlscripts\cgitest.pl line 360, <FILE> chunk
 4.
```

**>>>>>> EDIT 2 <<<<<<<<<**

After using trace I am non the wiser. Here is my log:

(this is now removing "quote()" and using placeholders)

```
    DBI 1.607-ithread default trace level set to 0x0/1 (pid 13524) at cgitest.pl line 10
    -> DBI->connect(*****************************************************)
    -> DBI->install_driver(mysql) for MSWin32 perl=5.010001 pid=13524 ruid=0 euid=0
       install_driver: DBD::mysql version 4.011 loaded from C:/Perl/site/lib/DBD/mysql.pm
    <- install_driver= DBI::dr=HASH(0x37be1fc)
    !! warn: 0 CLEARED by call to connect method
    <- connect('database=web110-accounts;host=79.170.44.110;', 'web110-accounts', ...)= DBI::db=HASH(0x37bdc8c) at DBI.pm line 638
    <- STORE('PrintError', 1)= 1 at DBI.pm line 690
    <- STORE('AutoCommit', 1)= 1 at DBI.pm line 690
    <- STORE('Username', 'web110-accounts')= 1 at DBI.pm line 693
    <> FETCH('Username')= 'web110-accounts' ('Username' from cache) at DBI.pm line 693
    <- connected(**********************************)= undef at DBI.pm line 699
    <- connect= DBI::db=HASH(0x37bdc8c)
    <- STORE('dbi_connect_closure', CODE(0x37c3634))= 1 at DBI.pm line 708
    <- prepare('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE KI = '9096699576bcc810df5bc311650c4ebd' ')= DBI::st=HASH(0x37bda24) at cgitest.pl line 61
    <- execute= 1 at cgitest.pl line 62
    <- rows= '1' at cgitest.pl line 63
    <- fetchrow_hashref= HASH(0x37bd514)24keys row1 at cgitest.pl line 64
    <- finish= 1 at cgitest.pl line 71
    <- disconnect= 1 at cgitest.pl line 72
   ****************************************************************************
   ****************************************************************************
    <- STORE('PrintError', 1)= 1 at DBI.pm line 690
    <- STORE('AutoCommit', 1)= 1 at DBI.pm line 690
    <- STORE('Username', 'web110-db-2')= 1 at DBI.pm line 693
    <> FETCH('Username')= 'web110-db-2' ('Username' from cache) at DBI.pm line 693
    <- connected('DBI:mysql:database=web110-db-2;host=79.170.44.110;', 'web110-db-2', ...)= undef at DBI.pm line 699
    <- connect= DBI::db=HASH(0x3d615ac)
    <- STORE('dbi_connect_closure', CODE(0x3d60f6c))= 1 at DBI.pm line 708
    <- prepare('INSERT INTO ? ( headData, headDataOutput ) VALUES ( ?, ? )')= DBI::st=HASH(0x351659c) at cgitest.pl line 263
    <- prepare('INSERT INTO ? ( bodyData, bodyDataOutput ) VALUES ( ?, ? )')= DBI::st=HASH(0x37bd914) at cgitest.pl line 264
    <- prepare('INSERT INTO page_names (linkFromRoot, linkTrue, page_name, table_name, navigation, location) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )')= DBI::st=HASH(0x3d575fc) at cgitest.pl line 265
    <- quote("http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/index.php")= "'http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/index.php'" at cgitest.pl line 271
    <- prepare("SELECT * FROM page_names WHERE linkTrue = 'http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/index.php' ")= DBI::st=HASH(0x3d571bc) at cgitest.pl line 272
    <- execute= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 273
    <- rows= '0' at cgitest.pl line 274
    <- quote("The Mobile Makeover - Mobile Beautician")= "'The Mobile Makeover - Mobile Beautician'" at cgitest.pl line 289
    <- prepare("SELECT * FROM page_names WHERE page_name = 'The Mobile Makeover - Mobile Beautician' ")= DBI::st=HASH(0x3d56fdc) at cgitest.pl line 290
    <- execute= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 291
    <- rows= '0' at cgitest.pl line 292
    <- DESTROY(DBI::st=HASH(3d54254))= undef at cgitest.pl line 287
    <- do('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `6959bbd13fdb4df586a5b9d08aae1153_body` (
                    `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
                    `bodyData` TEXT NOT NULL, 
                    `bodyDataOutput` TEXT NOT NULL 
                    ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;')= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 362
    <- do('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `6959bbd13fdb4df586a5b9d08aae1153_header` (
                    `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
                    `headData` TEXT NOT NULL, 
                    `headDataOutput` TEXT NOT NULL 
                    ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;')= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 363
    !! ERROR: 1064 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''6959bbd13fdb4df586a5b9d08aae1153_header' ( headData, headDataOutput ) VALUES ( ' at line 1' (err#0)
    <- execute('6959bbd13fdb4df586a5b9d08aae1153_header', '<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="The Mobile Makeover offers a wide range of services and treatments all from the luxuary of your own home!" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Mobile Makeover, Beauty Therapist, Beautician, Therapist, Mobile Therapist, Mansfield, Nottinghamshire" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
<meta name="author" content="ACT Web Designs" />
<meta name="copyright" content="The Mobile Makeover" />
<meta name="publisher" content="ACT Web Designs" />
<meta name="country" content="United Kingdom" />
<meta name="city" content="Mansfield, Nottinghamshire" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> 
<meta name="verify-v1" content="4lZIaMmjLMq+UA8nkPYB9RjF5RreNwF3Mzurm9JYvQM=" />
<title>The Mobile M...', ...)= undef at cgitest.pl line 365
    !! ERROR: 1064 CLEARED by call to execute method
    !! ERROR: 1064 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''6959bbd13fdb4df586a5b9d08aae1153_body' ( bodyData, bodyDataOutput ) VALUES ( '<' at line 1' (err#0)
    <- execute('6959bbd13fdb4df586a5b9d08aae1153_body', '<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="innerHeader">
                <h1><span>The Mobile Makeover - Mobile Beauty Therapist - Mansfield Nottinghamshire</span></h1>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php include("php/navigation.php"); ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content1" class="content vis">
                <h2>Welcome to The Mobile Makeover</h2>
                <div class="image1">
                </div>
                <p>Home visit appointments are designed to save you time and stress, by providing a service in the comfort of your own home, no need to worry about travel and traffic or facing the cold night air after a relaxing treatment.</p>
                <p>If you have a baby or a toddler The Mobile Makeover can help you put together a package of <a href="beauty-treatments.php" title="link to treatments page">treatments</a> that is ada...', ...)= undef at cgitest.pl line 366
    !! ERROR: 1064 CLEARED by call to execute method
    <- execute("public_html/index.php", "http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/index.php", ...)= 1 at cgitest.pl line 367
    <- DESTROY(DBI::st=HASH(3d56f5c))= undef at cgitest.pl line 270
    <- quote("http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/about-us-the-mobile-makeover.php")= "'http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/about-us-the-mobile-makeover.php'" at cgitest.pl line 271
    <- prepare("SELECT * FROM page_names WHERE linkTrue = 'http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/about-us-the-mobile-makeover.php' ")= DBI::st=HASH(0x3d56d9c) at cgitest.pl line 272
    <- execute= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 273
    <- rows= '0' at cgitest.pl line 274
    <- quote("The Mobile Makeover - About Us")= "'The Mobile Makeover - About Us'" at cgitest.pl line 289
    <- prepare("SELECT * FROM page_names WHERE page_name = 'The Mobile Makeover - About Us' ")= DBI::st=HASH(0x3b07814) at cgitest.pl line 290
    <- execute= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 291
    <- rows= '0' at cgitest.pl line 292
    <- DESTROY(DBI::st=HASH(3d54254))= undef at cgitest.pl line 287
    <- do('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `30df18a64311aa9aaaa9576b030f0f83_body` (
                    `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
                    `bodyData` TEXT NOT NULL, 
                    `bodyDataOutput` TEXT NOT NULL 
                    ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;')= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 362
    <- do('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `30df18a64311aa9aaaa9576b030f0f83_header` (
                    `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
                    `headData` TEXT NOT NULL, 
                    `headDataOutput` TEXT NOT NULL 
                    ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;')= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 363
    !! ERROR: 1064 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''30df18a64311aa9aaaa9576b030f0f83_header' ( headData, headDataOutput ) VALUES ( ' at line 1' (err#0)
    <- execute('30df18a64311aa9aaaa9576b030f0f83_header', '<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content=">My name is Kelly Knight, I am a highly Qualifed Mobile Beauty Therapist. I have trained in NVQ Level 2 and NVQ level 3 in Beauty Therapy with many additional courses and training..." />
<meta name="keywords" content="Mobile Makeover, About Us, Beauty Therapist, Mobile Therapist, Mansfield, Nottinghamshire" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
<meta name="author" content="ACT Web Designs" />
<meta name="copyright" content="The Mobile Makeover" />
<meta name="publisher" content="ACT Web Designs" />
<meta name="country" content="United Kingdom" />
<meta name="city" content="Mansfield, Nottinghamshire" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> 
<title>The Mobile Makeover - About U...', ...)= undef at cgitest.pl line 365
    !! ERROR: 1064 CLEARED by call to execute method
    !! ERROR: 1064 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''30df18a64311aa9aaaa9576b030f0f83_body' ( bodyData, bodyDataOutput ) VALUES ( '<' at line 1' (err#0)
    <- execute('30df18a64311aa9aaaa9576b030f0f83_body', '<body id="aboutUsPage">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="innerHeader">
                <h1><span>The Mobile Makeover - About Us</span></h1>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php include("php/navigation.php"); ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content1" class="content vis">
                <h2>About Us - Kelly Night</h2>
                <div class="image1">
                </div>
                <p>My name is Kelly Knight, I am a highly Qualified Mobile Beauty Therapist. I have trained in NVQ Level 2 and NVQ level 3 in Beauty Therapy with many additional courses and training gained within my time in the beauty industry. I have gained my years of experience from working at one of the UK's biggest Hotels &amp; Spa chains where i worked as a salon supervisor. After being approached by a number of people to go mobile to their homes i recognised that the...', ...)= undef at cgitest.pl line 366
    !! ERROR: 1064 CLEARED by call to execute method
    <- execute("public_html/about-us-the-mobile-makeover.php", "http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/about-us-the-mobile-makeover.php", ...)= 1 at cgitest.pl line 367
    <- DESTROY(DBI::st=HASH(3d56f1c))= undef at cgitest.pl line 270
    <- quote("http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/beauty-products-used.php")= "'http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/beauty-products-used.php'" at cgitest.pl line 271
    <- prepare("SELECT * FROM page_names WHERE linkTrue = 'http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/beauty-products-used.php' ")= DBI::st=HASH(0x3d56f3c) at cgitest.pl line 272
    <- execute= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 273
    <- rows= '0' at cgitest.pl line 274
    <- quote("The Mobile Makeover - Beauty Products Used")= "'The Mobile Makeover - Beauty Products Used'" at cgitest.pl line 289
    <- prepare("SELECT * FROM page_names WHERE page_name = 'The Mobile Makeover - Beauty Products Used' ")= DBI::st=HASH(0x3d545a4) at cgitest.pl line 290
    <- execute= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 291
    <- rows= '0' at cgitest.pl line 292
    <- DESTROY(DBI::st=HASH(3d54684))= undef at cgitest.pl line 287
    <- do('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `02b5f135f611c1d7b0ec090182bc6cf5_body` (
                    `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
                    `bodyData` TEXT NOT NULL, 
                    `bodyDataOutput` TEXT NOT NULL 
                    ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;')= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 362
    <- do('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `02b5f135f611c1d7b0ec090182bc6cf5_header` (
                    `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
                    `headData` TEXT NOT NULL, 
                    `headDataOutput` TEXT NOT NULL 
                    ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;')= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 363
    !! ERROR: 1064 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''02b5f135f611c1d7b0ec090182bc6cf5_header' ( headData, headDataOutput ) VALUES ( ' at line 1' (err#0)
    <- execute('02b5f135f611c1d7b0ec090182bc6cf5_header', '<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="We use a wide range of the finest products on the market today. Below is a short brief of just a few of the names which we believe give you the best results - we do not compromise when it comes to quality." />
<meta name="keywords" content="Mobile Makeover, Beauty Therapist, Beauty Products, Jessica, Calgel, Eve Taylor, Tantrick, Therapist, Mansfield, Nottinghamshire" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
<meta name="author" content="ACT Web Designs" />
<meta name="copyright" content="The Mobile Makeover" />
<meta name="publisher" content="ACT Web Designs" />
<meta name="country" content="United Kingdom" />
<meta name="city" content="Mansfield, Nottinghamshire" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compa...', ...)= undef at cgitest.pl line 365
    !! ERROR: 1064 CLEARED by call to execute method
    !! ERROR: 1064 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''02b5f135f611c1d7b0ec090182bc6cf5_body' ( bodyData, bodyDataOutput ) VALUES ( '<' at line 1' (err#0)
    <- execute('02b5f135f611c1d7b0ec090182bc6cf5_body', '<body id="aboutUsPage">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="innerHeader">
                <h1><span>The Mobile Makeover - Beauty Products</span></h1>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php include("php/navigation.php"); ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content1" class="content vis">
                <h2>Beauty products that we use</h2>
                <div class="image1">
                </div>
                <p>We use a wide range of the finest products on the market today. Below is a short brief of just a few of the names which we believe give you the best results - we do not compromise when it comes to quality.<br /> - <em>Kelly Knight</em></p>
            </div>
            <div class="content vis norm">
                <h2>Jessica</h2>
                <div class="image3">
                </div>
                <p>The Jessica &copy; nail products are de...', ...)= undef at cgitest.pl line 366
    !! ERROR: 1064 CLEARED by call to execute method
    <- execute("public_html/beauty-products-used.php", "http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/beauty-products-used.php", ...)= 1 at cgitest.pl line 367
    <- DESTROY(DBI::st=HASH(3d6982c))= undef at cgitest.pl line 270
    <- quote("http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/beauty-treatments.php")= "'http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/beauty-treatments.php'" at cgitest.pl line 271
    <- prepare("SELECT * FROM page_names WHERE linkTrue = 'http://www.themobilemakeover.co.uk/beauty-treatments.php' ")= DBI::st=HASH(0x3d56edc) at cgitest.pl line 272
    <- execute= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 273
    <- rows= '0' at cgitest.pl line 274
    <- quote("The Mobile Makeover - Beauty Treatments")= "'The Mobile Makeover - Beauty Treatments'" at cgitest.pl line 289
    <- prepare("SELECT * FROM page_names WHERE page_name = 'The Mobile Makeover - Beauty Treatments' ")= DBI::st=HASH(0x3d6b48c) at cgitest.pl line 290
    <- execute= '0E0' at cgitest.pl line 291
    <- rows= '0' at cgitest.pl line 292
    <- DESTROY(DBI::st=HASH(3d6c674))= undef at cgitest.pl line 287
    <- do('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `22e64cef7d70fa952ce7444f158e2c4e_body` (
                    `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
                    `bodyData` TEXT NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Maybe you need to quote()/placeholder the table names too. 
Or is it createXtable that's failing? I can't see where that's defined... Suggest you log all of the built SQL statements to a log file. That will probably help you see where the problem is.

Comment: When you have problems, create the smallest script possible that demonstrates the issue. That helps you narrow the focus of the question and keeps distracting information away from anyone who might answer. :)

Comment: Variable interpolation inside a SQL command?  "Well there's your problem..."

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to see for sure what's going wrong, but I think Andreas Bonini is correct that you've got quoting problems.

However, he has accidentally referred you to a PHP function ;-)

You can use DBI's **[quote method](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.609/DBI.pm#quote)** for the same effect. (Update: **oops**, you used it already for the data items. But perhaps you need to use it - or placeholders - for the table name variables too?)

However, it's considered better practice by most people to use **[placeholder values](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=7548)**:

```
while (something) {
    # I've imagined you're looping over the data

    $dbh->do("INSERT INTO $headerTable ( headData, headDataOutput ) 
      VALUES ( $headContents, $headContents )")
        or die " error: Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;
}
```

becomes:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO ? ( headData, headDataOutput ) 
                  VALUES ( ?, ? )") 
                    or die " error: Couldn't prepare : " . DBI->errstr;)

# later...
while (something) {
    # loop over the data

    $sth->execute($headerTable, $headContents, $headContents) 
      or die "couldn't execute: " . $sth->errstr;
}
```

**Untested... sorry ;-)**

I'm not 100% sure you can use a placeholder for the table name, but I don't really see why not, so I suggest trying it. If not, you should quote() the table name as described above.

Assuming your code runs in a loop, you can prepare the statement handler ($sth) once outside the loop and run execute several times, which should save some time if you have many inserts to do.

HTH

Comment: sorry, you did quote()... missed it looking too closely at the errors  not the code;-)
Anyway, placeholders are still (usually) a good thing so I guess I'll leave it.

Comment: Thanks for the time to write the above! will try the place holders. And also I tried using quote for the table name but gave me an error and couldnt get round it ( which i thought was odd). I'll post back soon.

Comment: Do you know if using the above method automatically adds quotes as the data in my DB has quotes around it?

Comment: It would get double-quoted if you're still calling the quote() method whilst using placeholders, I think... To be honest, though it's worth trying I'm less convinced that quoting is the problem and think you should log or trace your SQL to see what's wrong with it. The cause will probably be obvious when you see the broken SQL. Either add logging statements, or turn on tracing (I think tracing can be done at DBI level and probably MySQL level too).

Comment: have you a link to hand where i can find info on logging/tracing?